# Remove tabindex

Tags: browser, tabindex

How to remove default tabindex to the browser url?

Comment: What language? Try to provide us with more information

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to control the tab index for the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no way you can *remove* tabbing order. You can redefine it, adding the `tabindex` property to elements, setting numeric values on them. The lower the value the earlier the element gets focus.